# LED lamps and fluoro replacements

Tags: led

I  have  recently  purchased   LED  lamps   and magnet attached circular units  to  replace  old  fluoresent  tube units. The individual  lamps in the  format  of a  standard  240v  lightbulb  are  no problem. But  the  circular  units  and two flush mounted  down lights remain  permanently  slightly  lit  when  turned  off. One  of  the  circular  magnet  attached units in particular is  visibly  lit   in  daylight. The  remainder   can only  be  noticed  at  night. I  have  tried  reversing  the  wiring but  that  has  no effect. There  is  no  earth/ground  wire. To check  for  earth leakage via  the   lamp  body (which  is  fixed  to the  ceiling to an  all  steel  framed  building) I  put  insulation  tape  under  the  magnetic   mounts even though  the  lamp unit  is  powder  coated. This  made  no difference. There  are  no   dimmers, only  simple  mechanical  switches. The  only  way  to  fully  kill them is  to  switch  off  the  main supply. Am I missing   something   obvious ?

Comment: how do you switch them on and off *other* than by turning off the mains supply to them???

Comment: Just to make sure, the switches don’t light up when off, correct?

Comment: looks like you may have a serious problem in the breaker panel or in the building wiring

Comment: Wherever you are- is one side of the mains at essentially ground potential or are both 'hot' at 120VAC  wrt earth?

Comment: Are you sure the switches are purely mechanical?  Wall switches with neon indicators can allow sufficient current to dimly illuminate LED lamps.

Comment: The  switches  are simple  mechanical  with  no indicator lights.

Comment: If  the mains  supply is  incorrect/reversed  could  the  rcbo be back feeding? I  have  been  assuming load  and  neutral were  correct according  to  colour code. The  supply is  temporary to a new construction via  a builders pole fed  from a  neighbours  house so it maybe  reversed  at source !

Comment: @DavidNichols reversed hot - neutral will not cause your problem. Cheap or mismatched LED's on the same circuit will. I have experienced this myself. LED's have a power driver that is Pulse Width Modulated current control - mismatching can cause problems, your units are always on via potential on the neutrals typical ~2VAC, no grounding means problems like this will occur. It bleeds to the LED and it appears dim. You either need a ground or better LED lamps.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change out the LED's for a better model light or add in a real ground. Changing the LED's is cheaper and easier.

Did you leave the Florescent Assemblies in place with their transformer ? Or did you remove that ?

I have experienced this in a ceiling fan unit that had a remote control even some to be as bright as 50%.

I have also experienced this by mismatching LED's on the same lamp assembly:

- LED's and Compact fluorescent bulbs.
- LED's from one manufacturer with LED's from another manufacturer.

In all of the above cases changing the LED out for a different manufacturer fixed the issues. I now use all CREE or all Philips in my lamp assemblies and I have no issues.